# Using hosts: localhost and delegate_to causes kerberos UNREACHABLE! error?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

These plays work completely on (non-tower) ansible command line, tower command line, but not in the tower GUI. I've trimmed it down to 3 plays. The first 2 work in the tower GUI, but not the 3rd play. I am obviously missing something basic ...
 **ping shows good connections**

```
- name: works on all ansible versions 
  hosts: comp1.private.net
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
     - win_ping:

- name: works on all ansible versions
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
     ping:

- name: doesn't work in tower GUI.
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
     - win_stat:
         path: C:\blah\blah
       delegate_to: comp1.private.net
```

Throws fatal: [localhost] unreachable! kerberos cert  **obviously this means comp1**

What am I missing here??
Why did it work on the command lines? Sounds like a bug.

**command line used:** ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory abovePlay.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(update) Needed to add localhost to inventory prior to inventory inport.
also add variable **ansible_connection: local**

Apparently, for the ansible command line (ansible-playbook) it has a default localhost. For the ansible GUI, it doesn't automatically import the host_vars/localhost file when using **tower-manage inventory-import** command.